# Finding the closest location to a lat and long value

Tags: hive, geospatial, geohashing

I have two tables `t1` and `t2` (`t1` has 1/10th of the size of `t2`). Each table has two columns `<Lat, Long>` that contain the latitude and longitude of some points. For each row in `t1` I'd like to find the row in `t2` that is the closest to it. What would be the most efficient query for doing this? Does Hive have any sort of libraries for geospatial search?

Comment: Just to give a little help to the next person who is doing this: I ended up moving my data to Solr and used its quick geospatial search to query. Solr was super fast in doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do a bit of trig.

Please refer to this article on [Database Journal](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/mysql-calculating-distance-based-on-latitude-and-longitude.html)

The last routine I believe is what you are looking for (you'll need to modify it for your use):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE closest_restaurants_optimized`
(IN units varchar(5), IN lat Decimal(9,6), IN lon Decimal(9,6), 
IN max_distance SMALLINT, IN limit_rows MEDIUMINT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE ONE_DEGREE_CONSTANT TINYINT;
    DECLARE EARTH_RADIUS_CONSTANT SMALLINT;
    DECLARE lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2 float;  
    IF units = 'miles' THEN
        SET ONE_DEGREE_CONSTANT   = 69;
        SET EARTH_RADIUS_CONSTANT = 3959;
    ELSE -- default to kilometers
        SET ONE_DEGREE_CONSTANT   = 111;
        SET EARTH_RADIUS_CONSTANT = 6371;
    END IF;  
    SET lon1 = lon-max_distance/abs(cos(radians(lat))*ONE_DEGREE_CONSTANT);
    SET lon2 = lon+max_distance/abs(cos(radians(lat))*ONE_DEGREE_CONSTANT);
    SET lat1 = lat-(max_distance/ONE_DEGREE_CONSTANT);
    SET lat2 = lat+(max_distance/ONE_DEGREE_CONSTANT);
    SELECT pm1.post_id, p.post_title,
        ROUND((EARTH_RADIUS_CONSTANT * acos( cos( radians(lat) ) 
            * cos( radians(pm1.meta_value) ) 
            * cos( radians(pm2.meta_value) - radians(lon)) + sin(radians(lat)) 
            * sin( radians(pm1.meta_value)))
        ), 3) AS distance
    FROM goodfood_wp_md20m_postmeta AS pm1, 
        goodfood_wp_md20m_postmeta AS pm2,
        goodfood_wp_md20m_posts    AS p 
    WHERE pm1.meta_key = 'latitude' AND pm2.meta_key = 'longitude'
    AND pm1.post_id = pm2.post_id
    AND pm1.post_id = p.id
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND pm2.meta_value between lon1 and lon2 
    AND pm1.meta_value between lat1 and lat2
    ORDER BY distance ASC
    LIMIT limit_rows;
END
```